# Sharepoint services through its web services from PHP client

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

How can I connect Microsoft Sharepoint services through its web services from PHP client? we want to use auto authentication as the user will not be able to pass the credential.

Comment: What do you mean "auto authentication"? Windows authentication and impersonation?

Comment: I mean users credential shall be automatically understood by the SP service, it should use the credentials of the user running client application

Comment: What you request is extremely hard. I would suggest creating a windows user and then use those credentials when you connect to the WS through php, if that suits requirement of course